# gradle doLast executed before actions

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

According to the gradle documents, gradle executes a task as the following order:

configuration->doFirst->actions->doLast.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
task hello << {
    println "${hello.message}"
}

hello << {
    println "${hello.message} 2"
}

configure(hello, {
    ext.message = 'hello'
    description = "Hello task declared in project '${project.name}'"
    doFirst {
        println 'hello do first'
    }
    doLast {
        println 'hello do last'
    }
})

hello << {
    println "${hello.message} 3"
}

hello << {
    println "${hello.message} 4"
}
```

the output of this task is:

```
:hello
hello do first
hello
hello 2
hello do last
hello 3
hello 4

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.83 secs
```

The doLast is executed before the last two actions, please help to clarify.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The left shift operator (`<<`) means the same as `doLast`. Also, I'd like to clarify that `doFirst` and `doLast` *are* actions. `doFirst` actions are executed before `doLast` actions.